# Tabs to replace content on page with another HTML's file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been building a website using four separate links to replace the content of the home page with the other html's files information. The script works on each individual page where clicking other links erases the information of the site then when clicking the link of the current site, the information reappears. But I cannot get it to use one html site and have the information of all four.

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'Home')">Home</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'Tickets')">Tickets</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'Map')">Map</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openLink(event, 'Schedule')">Schedule</button>
    </div>

    <div id="Home" class="tabContent"><br>
        <h2 id="person"></h2><br>
        <p>Information and content here </p><br>
    </div>
    <!-- new site information will erase above content and load new page with bottom div -->
    <div id="result" class="tabContent">
    </div>
```

JS/JQuery:

```
$("#result").load("tickets.html #Tickets");
$("#result").load("map.html #Map");
$("#result").load("schedule.html #Schedule");

function openLink(evt, link) {

var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}

tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}

document.getElementById(link).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `But I cannot get it to use one html site and have the information of all four.`? Explain the problem in detail please.

Comment: On the home page, it has the original content displaying inside the div. When I click a new tab, rather than hyperlinking to the other html file I want it to clear the content, and grab the div content of the other page. It will clear the content when clicking other tabs, and the home content reappears when clicking that link. But the other 3 links all remain blank with no content.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the new code:

```
function eachButtons(a,b) {
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i in list) {
        if (list[i].className === a) {
            list[i].onclick = b;
        }
    }
}
```

how to use?, look:

```
eachButtons('class','action');
```

example:

html:

```
<body>
    <button className="link">google</button>
    <button className="link">bing</button>
</body>
```

script:

```
function myfunction() {alert('welcome');}
eachButtons('link',myfunction);
```

this will make a onclick alert for all buttons with link classname.

wrong code input example:

```
eachButtons('youclass',youfunction(ThisBacketsAreWrong));
```

Comment: So use that function instead of my openLink function and keep the .load function? I thought something might be wrong with that. Can try your function. Thanks!

Comment: Yes already, modified, now have support to keep the event .load, use de new updated code.

Comment: Using that code, the content on the page becomes "undefined".

Comment: Using this for all 4 buttons:                                                                                            
button class="tablinks" onclick="replaceContent('Home')">Home</button>

Comment: wait i will do a special function for this, wait

Comment: To understand it better, I just replace the tickets.html #Ticket); Tickets for each button. For each of the four links?

Comment: Ok wait im working on that, i will made a functon for this

Comment: eachButtons, make a loop for all buttons with you custom class name, and  add the onclick listener for all

Comment: but u need specify the function for do example: eachButtons('youclass',youfunction), important not use backets when u use eachButtons.